# What are the Apache RewriteCond flags?

Tags: apache

The page for `RewriteCond` is broken:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteCond?src=contextnavpagetreemode

I can't find any information on flags like `-f` and `!-f` and `-d`.

So this is a really open ended question:

What are they, and how do they work?

Here is a snippet of the code I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Which version of Apache are we talking about? This is the latest: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Any version will do (assuming the devs aren't changing these things willy nilly).  Thank you for the link, it includes a list of flags for RewriteCond

Comment: Yup, that's the docs for the latest version